# Pyscript in Django application

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, pyscript

I am wondering if we could use pyscript on HTML pages inside a Django project.

I'd tried to use it but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

this is the code :

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" >
            <center><h3><py-script> print('Now you can!') </py-script></h3></center>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was using Django==2.2.28 then I upgraded it to the last version Django==4.0.4 both didn't work and I get a black page!.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I use Pyscript with Django 4. What is the problem you have? Update your question with details on the problem.

Comment: ok, I did the changes also I upgraded the Django version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the solution.

I was using IDM that was catch any download in the browser.
So I deleted the file extension from IDM (.TAR) so my browser was able to download and use the pyodide_py.tar file.

(you should wait for a little python is slow :) )

Many thanks